# Under what condition(s) is an orthogonal projection of a vector is equal to the vector itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am currently studying for an Introduction to Linear Algebra course final exam. My professor gave us a list of guiding questions and concepts we should know, and this was one of them.

As far as I know, orthogonal vectors, under normal conditions, are linearly independent of one another. This is part of the reason why this question is so confusing to me.

As for solutions, my thoughts went to whether the answer to this was if both of the vectors were the **0** vector. However, I'm still unsure if this solution is correct. Maybe I'm not fully grasping the relationship between a vector and its orthogonal projection. Any guidance?

Comment: think of a simple example. Imagine orthogonal projection in $\Bbb{R}^3$ onto the subspace $S=\text{span}(e_1,e_2)=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3\,:\, z=0\}$, i.e the $x$-$y$ plane. Take some simple examples of vectors, and calculate their orthogonal projections onto the $x$-$y$ plane. What do you get? Is it the same or different from what you started with? Try another vector. Then, try another. Try many different "types" of vectors pointing in various directions. Are any directions special? etc. This is how you approach problems when you're completely stuck.

Comment: Look more carefully at the definition of an orthogonal projection. In particular, the orthogonal projection of a vector is generally not orthogonal to that vector.